# Git broken after restoring to new server - how to resolve?

Tags: git

my magento dev workflow has been:

- localhost dev PC with git setup
- push to bitbucket repo
- push bitbucket repo to live server

Yesterday the live server died (RAID errors or something). The hosting company gave me a new server with new IP etc.

To get the site up and running quickly, I just FTP'd the whole repo from my PC to the live server, uploading the last version of the database. All good, site back online within 2 hours.

However, the git link is now broken. Going into the new server, `git status` reported:

> error: bad index file sha1 signature. fatal: index file corrupt

So I deleted the index on the server (following some tips found here). But that gives another error:

> error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
>   fatal: object 72264d99759a1d21b2f532ab0eb04a57fde7021d is corrupted".

So, now I don't really know where to start and how to get my git flow running again. Any tips?

Comment: Does the new server have a `.git` file?  Find this repository file on your local PC and then search for it in exactly the same place on the new server.

Comment: well in fact, i copied over the .git folder from my PC to the new server. I'm not sure I should have done that or not.

Comment: FYI. I just updated my SSH keys etc, to try and rule that out. They seem to be OK - I can SSH connect to bitbucket from the new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: bad index file sha1 signature. fatal: index file corrupt

Read that as "the .git folder contents are corrupt/not useful"

### Clone again

The simplest solution is to clone again. You don't need to nuke your restored working copy just the git folder. i.e.:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ git clone url-to-your-repo.git new
$ cd /the/install
$ mv .git /tmp/old-git # in case you want to take a look at something
$ mv /tmp/new/.git .
```

Comment: thanks - seems to work perfectly! I did have to re-add a whole bunch of files.. is that normal? And there was a huge list of mode changes for file permissions. But seems to work!

Comment: if it's a production server you shouldn't really have any untracked changes, depends what the changes are as to whether it's normal - could mean you had a different checked out branch before, for example. File mods can be ignored by config - probably wise to compare `.git/config` for your new clone and the old to identify config differences. `.git/HEAD` will tell you the name of the checked out branch/reference.